# Making sure that the features retained after dim reduction explain >= 90% of the variance in the original data

Tags: regression, variance, lasso, dimensionality-reduction

Say I have some data, with 400 features, I want to use these features to predict a continuous response variable and the data meet the assumptions to run a linear regression model. So I want to reduce my feature space, and I use lasso. Taking the nonzero coefficients I now notice that my feature space has been drastically reduced to 10 dimensions (10 features). But now I wonder, how do I make sure that the features that survive the lasso regression explain >= 90% of the variance of the original data set?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but why would you want this? If, for example, your lasso model achieves excellent predictive accuracy with only a few of the predictors, why would you be concerned that only a little variability within and among the predictors is used by the model? On the contrary, the model seems all the better for being able to do a lot with a little.

Comment: @Kodiologist well, because of the nature of the data, I won't be using the model for actual prediction, I will need a non parametric approach for the prediction, I'm only using lasso for the reduction of dimensions. The part of wanting the remaining features to explain 90% of the variance was just a thought, it seemed to me that "important" features determined by lasso should explain the largest amount of variance in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly, two approaches to dimension reduction in a supervised-learning problem are:

1. Do the dimension reduction first, without consideration of the DV, and then use the dimension-reduced IVs for predicting the DV.
2. Apply a predictive model that does dimension reduction in the process of trying to predict the DV using the IVs.

The lasso belongs to approach 2. If you want approach 1, use an unsupervised dimension-reduction method such as principal components analysis.

That said, if predictive accuracy is your goal, approach 2 is generally a better bet, because the relationships among the IVs may not have much to do with their relationship with the DV.